# Rails: return a string if no object found instead of sending the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Notification model that is associated to a User model through "origin_user".

I am looking for a shortcut to this:

```
if notification.origin_user.present?
  notification.origin_user.name
else
  "a user"
end
```

Isn't there magic all-in-one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
notification.origin_user.try(:name) || "a user"
```

But if youpromise a `User`, give a `User`. You could rely on the [NullObject Design Pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)